# Android Studio: $END$ and $SELECTION$ in live template

Tags: android-studio, live-templates

I cannot get cursor in $END$ position when template inserted without surrounding (with selected text it works fine).

```
//region MyRegion
$SELECTION$$END$
//endregion
```

Is it possible to solve it in any way?

*Android Studio version is 2.2.3.*

**UPDATE**
To make question clear I have added steps to reproduce:
1) Create live template (surrounding) as it is specified above.
2) Give it some name, for example #mrgn.
3) Inside some class try to use it. So type #mrgn and press TAB.

It should insert the following text:

```
public class SomeClass {
    //region MyRegion
    < cursor should be here
    //endregion
}
```

But it inserts text and place cursor in wrong place:

```
public class SomeClass {
    //region MyRegion
< cursor is here.. but spaces are inserted, so only cursor does not work.
    //endregion
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to add steps to reproduce, actual behaviour and expected behaviour ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by creating 2 Live Templates. one for the surround one without.

Unfortunately that means that you will need to put up with 2 different aliases.

'regionSur'

```
//region MyRegion
$SELECTION$$END$
//endregion
```

'region'

```
//region MyRegion
$END$
//endregion
```

This isn't so bad, as the only time you see the surround syntax is when using the keyboard shortcut, instead of the auto complete lists.

The actual bug lies in the behaviour of $selection$ when it is empty, $END$ works fine.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Not sure the solution is very suitable.. but it makes sense for my future template.

Comment: On top of this, (for me at least) while the cursor appears at the start of the line, typing will make it instantly correct itself to the correct indentation.